# Creating a form from a model - Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, forms

I am running into trouble here. Here is my form:

```
class PublishBiddingForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = Puja
        fields = ("title", "video", "photo", "bidding_end","starting_price")

    def save(self, commit=True):
        Puja = super(PublishBiddingForm, self).save(commit=False)
        if commit:
            Puja.save()
        return Puja
```

Here is my model:

```
class Puja(models.Model):
    seller = models.OneToOneField(Seller, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    video = models.FileField()
    photo = models.ImageField()
    published_date = models.DateTimeField("Published: ",default=timezone.now())
    bidding_end = models.DateTimeField()
    starting_price = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)
```

my view:

```
def is_seller(user):
    try:
        return user.is_authenticated and user.seller is not None
    except Seller.DoesNotExist:
        return False

@user_passes_test(is_seller)
def publish_bidding(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PublishBiddingForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            Puja = form.save()
            titulo = form.cleaned_data.get('title')
            messages.success(request, f"New bid created: {titulo}")

            return redirect("main:homepage")

        else:
            for msg in form.error_messages:
                messages.error(request, f"{msg}: {form.error_messages[msg]}")

            return render(request = request,
                          template_name = "user_templates/register.html",
                          context={"form":form})

    form = PublishBiddingForm
    return render(request = request,
                  template_name = "publish_bidding.html",
                  context={"form":form})
```

and the error:
[image]

Does anybody know what is going on ? I have a register form successfully implemented, and I used it as a model to create this one, but I only get errors.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit 1:
Here is my urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name= "main"

urlpatterns = [

    path("", views.homepage, name="homepage"),
    path("logout", views.logout_request, name="logout"),
    path("login", views.login_request, name="login"),
    path("register/", views.register, name="register"),
    path("account/", views.account, name="account"),
    path("publish_bidding/", views.publish_bidding, name="publish_bidding"),



]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the configuration of the URL file, it should be something like this:

```
from <app>.views import publish_bidding

urlpatterns = [
   path('accounts/loggin/', publish_bidding, name='publish')
]
```

You can have more info here:
[Django URL dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/)

Comment: Hey @Zerender, I edited my question. Can you see a problem with urls.py ? Thank you very much

Comment: You should change the url you are using to http://127.0.0.1/account/login/?next=/publish_bidding/, instead of http://127.0.0.1/accounts/login/?next=/publish_bidding/

Comment: Found the answer. It was a very stupid mistake, making some changes to my code, I deleted the database and migrations, and I forgot to make my user a Seller, so of course Django wouldn't let me in since I didn't pass the test "is_seller". 

Thanks to everyone, and sorry for the inconveniance.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem with your form, apparently.

The error is about Django not being able to find the url. The url is trying to find the `account*s*` view, when the view you have registered is `account`, without the 's'.